Snowpipe and handling schema evolution without re-ingesting the data from an external table
I am trying to implement snowpipe to ingest data from AWS S3 to snowflake and trying to figure out how to handle schema evolution i.e., column additions/changes without re-ingesting the data from an external table?

if you mean include new columns just for new records then you pause the pipe, re-create it with the new COPY statement and then re-start the pipe.
If you mean populate new columns for existing records then you can't - without re-loading the entire table. You wouldn't necessarily have to do this using Snowpipe; for example, while the pipe is paused you could copy all the historic data into a temporary table in Snowflake, use that as the source to merge into the target table to update the new column(s) and then drop the temp table and re-start the pipe

We are planning to look in to implementing schema evolution feature in snowflake:
https://docs.snowflake.com/user-guide/data-load-schema-evolution
